# Ubuntu: no WPA2-PSK option for wireless security

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

I'm trying to connect to a new router that has WPA2-PSK encryption.

In the connection window Ubuntu presents when choosing the network from the wifi menu, there are only the 3 WEP options (40/128 bits, 128 bits, and dynamic) plus LEAP. But no WPA2-PSK or any other WPA...

I know for sure my router is set to WPA2-PSK and not to WEP.

I'm on a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 0197

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar situation. It turned out that for some reason Ubuntu for Wireless-N network does see 2 ESSIDs with the same name but supporting different authentication methods. One of them supports WEP options and the other supports WPA option. It is not clear from the menu which one to choose, so you need to try one until you pick the right one.